Does git rebase Update All Commit IDs?
I know git rebase will update the SHA of the affected commits. But, correct me if I'm wrong, the parent commits will be updated too, then their parents would update, and so on. So, does the entire repository's commit history get updated as an effect of running a single rebase command? Or does it only affect up to the base of the branch being rebased?

Because of the way that git stores information about the relation between commits (children commits point to parent commits, not the other way around), only the rebased commits would get new commit IDs... if you are rebasing, even if the commit trees do not change (which is possible) you would get new commit IDs because the metadata will probably change (the committer would be changed or at least updated).

Suppose this is your repository
... -- * -- X -- A -- B -- C (master)
        \
         -- D -- E -- F (foo)

If you rebase foo on to master, you create three new commits: D' from D, E' from E, and F' from F. None of D, E, or F are updated; they remain exactly as they were. The main difference is that the reference foo no longer points to F; it points to F':
... -- * -- X -- A -- B -- C (master) -- D' -- E' -- F' (foo)
        \
         -- D -- E -- F

There is no reference to F, so at some point it will be eligible for garbage collection.  When that happens, there will be no remaining reference to E, and it will be eligible. When that happens, D is left with no remaining reference and it, too, will be garbage collected. *, however, had two references, D and X, so it remains.
None of *, X, A, B, or C are changed at all, nor are any commits prior to *,  nor is the reference master updated.

What do you mean with "exactly as they were"? I guess you do not mean in contents (say, diff between f and f' be empty).... That could only happen if  diff X~..C  is empty.

It's the same snapshot (ignoring changes necessary to resolve conflicts).
